# Struct within vector

Tags: c++

I am quite new to c++, so bear with me. 
I have a vector that consists of structs. They are both in a class. I am supposed to read data from a file(which works fine) and save it. But when I try to input information in any part of the struct, my program crashes.

This is in the class in the header:

```
class Content{
private:
    string discName;
    string discID;
    struct content{
        int number=1;
        string name;
        string type;
        int size;
        int track;
        int sect;
    }heck;
    vector <content> block;
public:
    Content();
    void read_int(fstream& file);
    void read_id(fstream& file);
    void read_string(fstream&, int, string);
    void read_type(fstream& file);
};
```

And this is one of the functions it uses:

```
void Content::read_int(fstream& file){
    int file_content;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&file_content), 1);
    this->block[0].track=file_content;
}
```

From what I have found, most people tend to do it the other way around, with a vector in a struct, is that better?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. On which line is the crash? Do you ever allocate space for the vector (eg by calling `resize`) ?

Comment: How are the vector's elements created?

Comment: Are you sure that `block.size() != 0` is true?

Comment: btw it looks a bit odd that you read a `char` just to reinterpret it as `int`. Why dont you simply read an `int`? or make `track` a `char` (if thats what it is)

Comment: `this->block[0].track=file_content;` are you sure that `this->block` has at least one element contained within it? Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities (at least):

First, the vector already contains element you want to set with values read from file, then you need to ensure that the vector already contains elements. Maybe in the constructor of `Content`? Something like `block.resize(n)`, for some appropriate `n`.

Second, the vector initially contains no element and you want to populate it with elements created with data read from the file. Something like:

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&file_content), sizeof file_content); // read data from file
content c; // construct an element
c.track = file_content; // set data of the element
this->block.push_back( c ); // add that new element to the vector
```

Beware to give appropriate size when reading in file. It seems like you tried to read an int, so the number of bytes to read should be the number of bytes to store an int: `sizeof int`.

Be also aware that your definition of `Content` contains a filed named `heck`... I doubt that what you need. I suspect that `struct content` is just a definition of a type for what is contained in the vector, so the following is better:

```
struct content {
    int number=1;
    string name;
    string type;
    int size;
    int track;
    int sect;
};

class Content{
private:
    string discName;
    string discID;
    vector <content> block;
public:
    Content();
    void read_int(fstream& file);
    void read_id(fstream& file);
    void read_string(fstream&, int, string);
    void read_type(fstream& file);
};
```

Note that type identifiers should have first letter capitalized. Then you may have:

```
struct ContentData {
    ....
};
class Content {
    ....
    vector<ContentData> block;
};
```

or alike.

A better choice would be to have a single function to read an int that returns an int and that you use appropriately:

```
void Content::read_int(fstream& file){
    int file_content;
    file.read(&file_content, sizeof file_content); // take care of returned value!!!
    return file_content;
}

Content c;
c.track = read_int(f);
c.size = read_int(f);
c.type = read_string(f);
c.name = read_string(f);
...
bloc.push_back( c );
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Then you may choose it as the accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

As comments suggested, you program probably crashes because there are no elements in block, so block[0] leads to undefined bahaviour. Try [std::vector::emplace_back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/) if you are using C++11 standard and want to add new element in the vector for each read value. Or if you want it always at first place for some reason, then initialize it in constructor or use this in your function:

```
void Content::read_int(fstream& file)
{
    int file_content = file.get(); //no need for reintepret casting ;)
    if (!block.empty())
        this->block[0].track=file_content;
    //possibly else to create the element if needed
}
```

To address your second question, there is no such thing as "most people tend to" or "better way" in this example. It's a matter of what you want to achieve. Vector in your struct is something different than vector holding your structs.
Here, you have an array which holds elements, where every element holds 4 ints and 2 strings. If you wanted to create vector in your struct, you'd have a single structure for each instace, holding 4 ints, 2 strings and a vector.